# Adding elements inbetween navigation links

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, navbar

I have the following code which makes/inputs my navigation into my site. The links are created through the admin panel. I want to add a '|' separator in between the links

**HTML**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
/* Register 'primary' navigation */

function wptutsplus_register_theme_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Main Navigation Menu');
}

add_action('init', 'wptutsplus_register_theme_menu');
```

Current output

```
Link 1     Link 2    ...
```

Desired output

```
Link 1   |   Link 2   ...
```

html

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated `v2`**

> You can use `after` parameter of [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters), with a small CSS trick.

Here is the code:

```
$menuParameters = [
    'container_class' => 'main-nav',
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'menu_class' => 'my_custom_class', //<-- add this
    'after' => '<span class="sep">|</span>' //<-- add this
];
wp_nav_menu($menuParameters);
```

Add this to you `style.css`

```
.my_custom_class li:last-child .sep{ display:none; }
```

---

*Alternative way (with pure PHP approach)*

```
$menuParameters = [
    'container_class' => 'main-nav',
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'after' => '|', //<-- add this
    'echo' => false //<-- add this
];

$nav_html = wp_nav_menu($menuParameters);
$needle = isset($menuParameters['after']) ? $menuParameters['after'] : '';
$index = strrpos($nav_html, $needle);
if ($index)
{
    echo substr_replace($nav_html, '', $index, strlen($needle));
}
else
{
    echo $nav_html;
}
```

**All code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would this put one on all the links then, cause I could style the link css itself, but then the last link would have it to, so the menu would end link4 |  ...

Comment: yes it will add `|` after every link, so that's why I have used `trim()` function to remove the last pipe `|` symbol. pls try it, it will work as I have tested in my end.

Comment: Ok awesome! thank you, I'm not familiar with the trim part so wasn't sure

Comment: Not seeming to work when I'm adding it to my functions.php, I assume its an issue on my end, Is there a specific way to include it?

Comment: @user3550879: Actually the error was at my end, I was using a theme with was overriding my nav CSS. So I have update my answer with 2 methods, both are tested with multiple theme and with no plugin install just  to double check my output. please have a loot at it.

Comment: oh ok, Should this go after I add action it, or can this fully replace the php I used

Comment: Yes you can fully replaced it with the any of the two method.

Comment: So it doesn't have to be registered as I have it written (I thought you have to register things like this ex. register_theme ...)? I ask cause when I replace my code with this, it seems to add two copies of the the menu overtop each other I updated my question with html used since I figure thats causing the copy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super sure how wordpress styles their links, but this should emulate that, I don't think simply inserting the textnodes will work.

```
.wp-navigation {
    border-right:2px solid black;
}
.wp-navigation:last-child {
    border-right:none;
}
```

Comment: problem is this would put one on the end link

Answer (score 0):

add the symbol |(as many as menu links you have) as u would add normally a custom link in the wordpress menu.

after that get the class or id of every element with devtools then apply this css to every one of the elements

```
.itemtofind{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

you can customize the css element as you wish , add padding, color, etc.
in the past i made a web page with that feature and everything was right.
when you are in mobile apply the correct media query and hidde the symbols | with this css to the elements

display:none

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS. Something like this should work.

```
.main-nav a:after {
     content: '|';
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 .5em;
}
```